# How to download all suppression list's records using Mailgun API

Tags: php, mailgun

I have developed the following code,

```
$domain = "domain";
$event = "unsubscribes";
//$nextPage = ''; // [bounces, unsubscribes, complaints]

// Initiate download on client browser
$filename = $domain."_".$event."_".date("c").".csv";
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);

// Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/unsubscribes");
//$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/events/" . explode("$domain/events/", $result->http_response_body->paging->next));

$html = "<table><tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

if(count($result->http_response_body->items) > 0) {
    foreach ($result->http_response_body->items as $key) {
         $html .= "<tr>
             <td>" .$key->address."</td></tr>";
    }

} 

$html .= "</table>";  

echo $html;
```

This gives log's unsubscribes not suppression list records. How to get only all suppression list records (for instance, unsubscribe rs).

Answer (score 0):

Suppressions are bounces, unsubscribes, and complaints.  You need to query all three endpoints to get this information.

Please check out [Mailgun-PHP](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php) if you don't want to write this code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already using the Mailgun PHP library, which is great. As per Jesse's answer, suppressions are split into bounces, unsubscribes and complaints.

Your code sample is currently fetching unsubscribes with this line:

```
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/unsubscribes");
```

...which you can change to fetch bounces with this:

```
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/bounces");
```

...or complaints like this...

```
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/complaints");
```

Mailgun's [API reference](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-suppressions.html#view-all-bounces) is pretty helpful for further help here.

Also note that the current version of the PHP API seems to default to using version 2 of the API when Mailgun actually recommend using V3. Version 2 only seems to return a small portion of your bounces which is somewhat frustrating, so it's worth making the upgrade. Run this before your other calls...

```
$mgClient->setApiVersion('v3');
```

...which should allow to request way more suppressions in one go (limit of 10,000 rather than 300, I believe). Hope this helps!